# Assign values of label into corresponding column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data series with act like a reference of certain values for specific labels. I would like to popualte the values for the corresponding "label/index" into another data frame. As an example

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], data=[[1, 2, "goat"], [4, 5, "monkey"] ,[7,8,"goat"]],columns=["I", "L","data"])
B = pd.DataFrame(index=["goat", "monkey", "sheep"], data=[[10], [ 40] ,[ 70]])
```

here `B` acts like a reference for the labels indicated as animals. I would like to add a column to data frame `A` and fill in the corresponding value for the animal in the `data column`, i.e. the final result should look like:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], data=[[1, 2, "goat",10], [4, 5, "monkey",40] ,[7,8,"goat",10]],columns=["I", "L","data","data value"])
```

I could loop over the unique values of `B` and just filter for the corresponding rows and add the value. But I feel there is a better way to do it in python

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) on `data` and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns in `B` so they appear as expected in `A`:

```
A = A.join(B.rename(columns={0: 'data value'}), on='data')
```

`A`:

```
   I  L    data  data value
0  1  2    goat          10
1  4  5  monkey          40
2  7  8    goat          10
```